# How to enable directory listing and resource serving on an Embedded Undertow Server?

Tags: java, servlets, undertow

In the example listed on the [undertow documentation site](http://undertow.io/undertow-docs/undertow-docs-1.4.0/index.html#undertow-servlet), it shows how to configure 2 servlets and their mappings. But I can't find how to configure the *default* Servlet to allow directory listing and resource serving.

```
DeploymentInfo servletBuilder = Servlets.deployment()
        .setClassLoader(ServletServer.class.getClassLoader())
        .setContextPath("/myapp")
        .setDeploymentName("test.war")
        .addServlets(
                Servlets.servlet("MessageServlet", MessageServlet.class)
                        .addInitParam("message", "Hello World")
                        .addMapping("/*"),
                Servlets.servlet("MyServlet", MessageServlet.class)
                        .addInitParam("message", "MyServlet")
                        .addMapping("/myservlet"));

DeploymentManager manager = Servlets.defaultContainer().addDeployment(servletBuilder);
manager.deploy();
PathHandler path = Handlers.path(Handlers.redirect("/myapp"))
        .addPrefixPath("/myapp", manager.start());

Undertow server = Undertow.builder()
        .addHttpListener(8080, "localhost")
        .setHandler(path)
        .build();
server.start();
```

It's an embedded undertow server in a runnable jar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When adding servlets, also add the *"default"* servlet in the list of servlets with

```
Servlets.servlet("default", DefaultServlet.class)
.addInitParam(DefaultServlet.DIRECTORY_LISTING, "true")
.addInitParam(DefaultServlet.DEFAULT_ALLOWED, "true")
.addInitParam(DefaultServlet.ALLOW_POST, "false")
.addInitParam(DefaultServlet.RESOLVE_AGAINST_CONTEXT_ROOT, "true")
```

Then before deploying the container add this to the `DeploymentInfo`

```
servletBuilder.setResourceManager(new ClassPathResourceManager(App.class.getClassLoader(), "webapp"));
```

Then anything you put inside the webapp folder that is packaged in the jar will work exactly the same as any normal war/webapp folder deployed in any app server.

You can use any name or folder, `webapp` was just an example.